# How to restore a database from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2000, restore

I've got a databe in SQL Server 2000 and older than it! And it's very old version. I can't restore to SQL Server 2012. Is that because of old version? How can I restore it? Is there any script or something like that?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2012 no longer supports restoring SQL Server **2000** databases. You need to take an intermediate step:

1. backup your SQL Server 2000 database
2. restore it to SQL Server 2005 / 2008 / 2008 R2
3. change the compatibility level to at least "90" (SQL Server 2005)
4. backup again from that intermediate server
5. *then* restore that second backup on SQL Server 2012

Or depending on size and complexity of your SQL Server 2000 database, it might be easier to just script out the structure and data into SQL scripts and then run those on SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Do make sure you test your application fully in the new environment before doing this in production, unless your use of SQL Server's features is very basic. Compatibility Level 80 is no longer supported so there may be changes in behaviours your code depends upon..

In fact I remember one of our applications experiencing a breaking change in the output of `FOR XML` queries when moving from 2000 to 2005 with compatibility level properly set, when cl=80 *was* officially supported.